# QGIS difference operation with XYZ tiles

Tags: qgis, differences, xyz-tiles

I have a regular layer from a database containing WKT polygons. I'm also using a XYZ Tiles layer of Google Maps. I would like to perform the `Vector` > `Geoprocessing Tools` > `Difference` operation between the two layers, except using an `XYZ Tiles` layer is not a possibility in the `Difference` dialog box (notice no `expand` arrow to allow access to `OpenStreetMap` or `gmm` (Google Maps)). QGIS 3.16 being used.

[image]

[image]

Comment: XYZ Tiles = Raster, your trying to using vector tools on raster data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Difference operation is an operation that only works with vector layers (as you can see from the fact that it's located in the vector menu). You can't process any raster with that. The OpenStreetMap Layer represents raster data from raster tiles. If you want to process OpenStreetMap data with the Difference operation, you should first download OSM data in vector format. However, as you don't mention what exactely you want to achieve using the Difference operation, there are maybe other options. So I suggest to open a new question where you explain what is your final goal.

By the way: as far as I know, XYZ tiles cannot be processed at all, not even as raster. So you can't use XYZ tiles in the raster calculator. They are here just as basemaps, for orientation purpose etc.

Comment: Export XYZ tiles to raster (geotiff) then they can use the raster tools.

Comment: remember that XYZ tiles are a **picture** of the data not actual data, so exporting to GeoTiff is unlikely to give good results